# Extracting table from UPS website using BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, html, pandas, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

Im trying to extract us diesel price surcharge by table id using the below code but its only reading until `<thead>` but not `<tbody>` what am i doing wrong?

```
url = 'https://www.ups.com/us/en/shipping/surcharges/fuel-surcharges.page'
response = requests.get(url)
print(response.status_code)
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content,"html.parser")
tables = soup.find(id="USDiesel")
print(tables)
tables_all = []
for tr in tables.find_all('tr'):
    data = []
    for td in tr.find_all('td'):
        data.append(td.text.strip())
    tables_all.append(data)
table_df = pd.DataFrame(tables_all)
headers = table_df.iloc[0]
UPS_Gfuelsurcharge_df  = pd.DataFrame(table_df.values[1:], columns=headers)
print(UPS_Gfuelsurcharge_df)
```

Answer (score 0):

The website uses ajax to load the table data.

```
import requests

res = requests.get("https://www.ups.com/assets/resources/fuel-surcharge/us.json")

print(res.json())
```

Comment: Can you suggest on how do i go about extracting the table im relatively new to this

Comment: @adolfsingh you get the values in the form of json. Loop through the json values. Refer - https://realpython.com/python-json/